# Redirecting to action(having paginated view) from another controller in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I am very new to MVC 4.Could you folks .please help me out with the following issue.
I have an Index action method where I am setting the number of records to be displayed after pagination.

Index action method is as shown

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? page){
        Provider providerList = new Provider();
        IList<Provider> providers = DAL.GetListofProviders.ToList();

        int pageSize = 5;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(providers.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
    }
```

The Index view is as shown.

```
 @using PagedList;
 @using PagedList.Mvc;
 @model IPagedList<DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
<head>
    <title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Providers List</h1><br/>
        <a class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1" href="/Provider/Create">Create</a><br/>

        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>Provider Type</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Certification</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:viewModel">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ProviderType"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
            <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
    <td><a class=" col-lg-2 btn btn-danger" id="del" onclick="" data-bind="attr: { href: '/Provider/Delete/'+ ProviderID }">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    Page @(Model.PageCount<Model.PageNumber? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
           @Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
    </div>   
  </body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

By Clicking the Create button,A user is directed to another page where data is entered into the forms and posted.

Script for posting is as shown.

```
   $("#Submit").on("click", function () {
       if (ValidatethisForm()) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Provider/Create",
               data: Provider
           });
        }
    });
```

In the Create Action,I am redirecting wrongfully to the Index method.

```
   public ActionResult Create(Provider provider)
    {
        try
        {
       DAL.InsertDataintoProviderTable(provider.ProviderType,provider.FirstName,provider.LastName);
            return RedirectToAction("Index(1)","Provider");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Kindly guide me in the right direction.Thanks.

Edit
ValidatethisForm method

```
   function ValidatethisForm() {
    if (Provider.ProviderType() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.FirstName() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.LastName() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.Certification() === "")
        return false
    else if (Provider.Specialization() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.ContactNumber() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.ContactEmail() === "")
        return false;
    else if (Provider.FacilityName() === "")
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

HTML of Create Page

```
  @model DEMO_JAN14.Models.Provider

@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <head>
   <title>CREATE PROVIDER</title>
</head>
 <body>
<div class="container">    
    <h1 class="col-sm-offset-2">Enter Provider Details:</h1><br />
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="ProviderDetailsForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">PROVIDER TYPE:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="ProviderType">
                <select class="form-control" data-bind="value: ProviderType" autofocus="autofocus">
                    <option>Select a Provider Type</option>
                    <option>Doctor</option>
                    <option>Facility</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FIRST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the First Name"   id="FirstName" data-bind="value: FirstName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FirstName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">LAST NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="LastName" data-bind="value: LastName" onkeypress="return onlyAlphabets(event);">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_LastName">Enter the first name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">CERTIFICATION:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="Certification" data-bind="value: Certification">
                    <option>Select a Certification</option>
                    <option>Doctor</option>
                    <option>Facility</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">SPECIALIZATION:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="Specialization" data-bind="value: Specialization">
                    <option>Select a Specialization</option>    
                    <option>Doctor</option>
                    <option>Facility</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">SSN:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the SSN" id="SSN" d data-bind="value: SSN" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="9">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_SSN">Enter the SSN</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">FACILITY NAME:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: FacilityName" placeholder="Enter the Facility Name" id="FacilityName">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_FacName">Enter the Facility name</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">CONTACT NUMBER:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: ContactNumber" placeholder="Enter the Contact Number" id="ContactNumber" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="10">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_ContactNum">Enter the Contact Number</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">EMAIL ADDRESS:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: ContactEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" id="EmailAddress">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_EmailAddress">Enter the Email Address</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-  4">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Create_Script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling the page with ajax and redirect doesn't work there like that. You need to perform the redirect from JavaScript by passing the url to it.

In your action method return the url of the action you want to redirect to:

```
public ActionResult Create(Provider provider)
{
    try
    {
   DAL.InsertDataintoProviderTable(provider.ProviderType,provider.FirstName,provider.LastName);
        string url = Url.Action("Index", "Provider");
        return Json(new {url});
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In you JavaScript grab that url and redirect to it:

```
   $("#Submit").on("click", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if (ValidatethisForm()) {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Provider/Create",
               data: Provider,
               success: function(result) {
                   if (result.url) {
                       location.href = result.url;
                   }
               }
           });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I just tried it.It did not work.I was still in the create page itself.

Comment: I have already tried the second option.Unfortunately it does not redirect to the index.I am stuck on the same create page.

Comment: Unfortunately,that did not work either.I am still on the same page.
Data is getting saved,so its definitely hitting the ajax call.The url changes to "http://localhost:49552/Provider/Create?" .. Could that have some bearing? By the way url varaiable contains "/"

Comment: Does it hit the `success` function?

Comment: I've added `preventDefault` call, please, try adding it

Comment: The changes that you suggested are not getting reflected in the scripts when I inspect the create page.I have added them in the JS file.I see it in VS but not when I run it.

Comment: Clear the cache, so that the scripts refresh

Comment: Nope,It did not work.Could you please tell me where I am supposed to add prevent default call.

Comment: I have included it in the answer

Comment: Ok .. Now its not even hitting the ajax call.Data is not getting saved at all.

Comment: Post the `ValidatethisForm` method and the html of the form itself

Comment: It's still not enough info to tell what's wrong. Debug your javascript to see why the `ValidatethisForm` function returns false.